# Как запустить цикл с нуля?

Tags: javascript

Пишу простую игру для практики, угадай слово. Проблема такая когда 10 жизней сгорает, нужно заново запускать функцию startGame, но все ломается. Т.е я допускаю 10 ошибок, алерт жму ок, вроде все обновляется но почему-то дальше на любую кнопку код реагирует тем, что начинает показывать "вы проиграли" и перезапускать функцию. В чем проблема? Почти каждая строчка закоментирована

```js
if(document.getElementById('start')){
    let start = document.getElementById('start'),                       /* Получение кнопки старт */
        stop = document.getElementById('stop'),                         /* Получение кнопки стоп */
        form = document.querySelector('.game-form');                    /* Получение формы */

    start.addEventListener('click', function(event){                    /* Клик по кнопке старт */
        toggleButton();                                                 /* Вызов функции hide кнопок и формы */
        startGame();                                                    /* Вызов функции запуска игры */
    });

    stop.addEventListener('click', function(event){                     /* Клик по кнопке стоп */
        toggleButton();                                                 /* Вызов функции hide кнопок и формы */
    });

    function toggleButton(){                                            /* Функция hide кнопок и формы */
        event.preventDefault();                                         /* Отмена действия по умолчанию */
        start.classList.toggle('header-button-hide');                   /* Показать или скрыть кнопку старт */
        stop.classList.toggle('header-button-hide');                    /* Показать или скрыть кнопку стоп */
        form.classList.toggle('game-form-hide');                        /* Показать или скрыть форму */
    }

    let arrayWords = [{                                                 /* Массив  слов */
        word: 'рыба',
        hint: 'Плавает в воде'
    },{
        word: 'птица',
        hint: 'Летает в небе'
    },{
        word: 'машина',
        hint: '4 колеса'
    },{
        word: 'стол',
        hint: 'За ним едят'
    }];

    function startGame(){                                               /* Функция запуска игры */
        let hp = 10,                                                    /* Переменная с ХП */
            number = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayWords.length),     /* Получаем рандомное число */
            word = arrayWords[number].word,                             /* Получаем нужное слово */
            hint = arrayWords[number].hint,                             /* Получаем нужную подсказку */
            answerArray = [],                                           /* Пустой массив для ответа */
            remainingLetters = word.length,                             /* Счетчик, сколько букв осталось */
            innerHp = document.getElementById('hp'),                    /* Получение блока вывода hp жизней*/
            innerHint = document.getElementById('hint'),                /* Получение блока вывода hint подсказки*/
            innerLetter = document.getElementById('letter'),            /* Получение блока вывода letter букв*/
            buttonEnter = document.getElementById('enter-letter'),      /* Кнопка отправки буквы */
            message = document.querySelector('.message');               /* Получение блока для сообщений */
            document.getElementById('input-letter').value = ''          /* Очистки инпута */

        innerHp.innerHTML = hp;                                         /* Вывод ХП */
        innerHint.innerHTML = hint;                                     /* Вывод подсказки */

        for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
            answerArray[i] = '_';                                       /* Заполнение пустого массива */
        }

        innerLetter.innerHTML = answerArray.join(' ');                  /* Вывод угаданных букв и замена запятых на пробел */

        buttonEnter.addEventListener('click', function(event){          /* Клик по кнопки отправки буквы */
            event.preventDefault();                                     /* Отмена действий по умолчанию */
            message.innerHTML = '';
            let enterLetter = document.getElementById('input-letter').value;    /* Получение буквы */
            document.getElementById('input-letter').value = ''          /* Очистки инпута */
            if(enterLetter.length !== 1){
                message.innerHTML = 'Введите 1 букву';                  /* Если поле ввода отличается от 1 */
            }else{
                message.innerHTML = '';
                let negation = false;                                   /* Отгаданна ли буква */
                for(let q = 0; q < word.length; q++){                   /* Перебор слова */
                    if(word[q] == enterLetter.toLowerCase()){           /* Если буквы совпадают */
                        answerArray[q] = enterLetter;                   /* Запись введенной буквы в массив */
                        innerLetter.innerHTML = answerArray.join(' ');  /* Вывод обновленного массива с буквами */
                        negation = true;                                /* Если буква есть */
                    }
                }

                if(!negation){
                    message.innerHTML = 'Буква не найдена';             /* Буква не найдена*/
                    hp--;                                               /* Отнять ХП */
                    innerHp.innerHTML = hp;                             /* Вывод ХП */
                }

                if(hp <= 0){
                    alert('Вы проиграли');                              /* Счетчик ХП меньше 0, вы проиграли */
                    startGame();                                        /* Запуск функции сначала */
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```css
body,
html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #7e57c2;
}

.header-button-hide{

}

.header-button{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
}

.header-button:active{
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}

.header-page{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.header-wrap{
    text-align: center;
}

.game-form{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.header-button-hide{
    display: none;
}

.game-form-hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Угадай слово</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header-page">
            <form class="header-wrap" method="GET" action="/start.php">
                <button id="start" class="header-button">Начать</button>
                <button id="stop" class="header-button header-button-hide">Остановить</button>
            </form>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="game">
                <form method="GET" action="/check.php" class="game-form game-form-hide">
                    <h2 class="message"></h2>
                    <p><span>Жизни:</span> <span id="hp"></span></p>
                    <p><span>Подсказка:</span> <span id="hint"></span></p>
                    <p><span>Ваши буквы:</span> <span id="letter"></span></p>
                    <label>Введите букву: <input type="text" name="letter" id="input-letter"></label>
                    <input type="submit" name="enter-letter" id="enter-letter">
                </form>
            </section>
        </main>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вынесите назначение обработчика кнопке `buttonEnter` (и объявление переменной `hp`) из функции `startGame`.

Answer (score 3):

Вы навешиваете на кнопку обработчик кнопки и замыкаете в нем переменные. Когда вы перезапускаете свою функцию `startGame()`, этот обработчик никуда не девается и хранит все переменные, которые были созданы до этого. В итоге у вас одновременно отрабатывают две функции, старая и новая. Как вариант отписываться от обработчика и создавать заново или переделывать логику на сброс переменных.

```js
if(document.getElementById('start')){
    let start = document.getElementById('start'),                       /* Получение кнопки старт */
        stop = document.getElementById('stop'),                         /* Получение кнопки стоп */
        form = document.querySelector('.game-form');                    /* Получение формы */

    start.addEventListener('click', function(event){                    /* Клик по кнопке старт */
        toggleButton();                                                 /* Вызов функции hide кнопок и формы */
        startGame();                                                    /* Вызов функции запуска игры */
    });

    stop.addEventListener('click', function(event){                     /* Клик по кнопке стоп */
        toggleButton();                                                 /* Вызов функции hide кнопок и формы */
    });

    function toggleButton(){                                            /* Функция hide кнопок и формы */
        event.preventDefault();                                         /* Отмена действия по умолчанию */
        start.classList.toggle('header-button-hide');                   /* Показать или скрыть кнопку старт */
        stop.classList.toggle('header-button-hide');                    /* Показать или скрыть кнопку стоп */
        form.classList.toggle('game-form-hide');                        /* Показать или скрыть форму */
    }

    let arrayWords = [{                                                 /* Массив  слов */
        word: 'рыба',
        hint: 'Плавает в воде'
    },{
        word: 'птица',
        hint: 'Летает в небе'
    },{
        word: 'машина',
        hint: '4 колеса'
    },{
        word: 'стол',
        hint: 'За ним едят'
    }];

    function startGame(){                                               /* Функция запуска игры */
        let hp = 10,                                                    /* Переменная с ХП */
            number = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayWords.length),     /* Получаем рандомное число */
            word = arrayWords[number].word,                             /* Получаем нужное слово */
            hint = arrayWords[number].hint,                             /* Получаем нужную подсказку */
            answerArray = [],                                           /* Пустой массив для ответа */
            remainingLetters = word.length,                             /* Счетчик, сколько букв осталось */
            innerHp = document.getElementById('hp'),                    /* Получение блока вывода hp жизней*/
            innerHint = document.getElementById('hint'),                /* Получение блока вывода hint подсказки*/
            innerLetter = document.getElementById('letter'),            /* Получение блока вывода letter букв*/
            buttonEnter = document.getElementById('enter-letter'),      /* Кнопка отправки буквы */
            message = document.querySelector('.message');               /* Получение блока для сообщений */
            document.getElementById('input-letter').value = ''          /* Очистки инпута */

        innerHp.innerHTML = hp;                                         /* Вывод ХП */
        innerHint.innerHTML = hint;                                     /* Вывод подсказки */

        for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
            answerArray[i] = '_';                                       /* Заполнение пустого массива */
        }

        innerLetter.innerHTML = answerArray.join(' ');                  /* Вывод угаданных букв и замена запятых на пробел */

        let listener = function(event){          /* Клик по кнопки отправки буквы */
            event.preventDefault();                                     /* Отмена действий по умолчанию */
            message.innerHTML = '';
            let enterLetter = document.getElementById('input-letter').value;    /* Получение буквы */
            document.getElementById('input-letter').value = ''          /* Очистки инпута */
            if(enterLetter.length !== 1){
                message.innerHTML = 'Введите 1 букву';                  /* Если поле ввода отличается от 1 */
            }else{
                message.innerHTML = '';
                let negation = false;                                   /* Отгаданна ли буква */
                for(let q = 0; q < word.length; q++){                   /* Перебор слова */
                    if(word[q] == enterLetter.toLowerCase()){           /* Если буквы совпадают */
                        answerArray[q] = enterLetter;                   /* Запись введенной буквы в массив */
                        innerLetter.innerHTML = answerArray.join(' ');  /* Вывод обновленного массива с буквами */
                        negation = true;                                /* Если буква есть */
                    }
                }

                if(!negation){
                    message.innerHTML = 'Буква не найдена';             /* Буква не найдена*/
                    hp--;                                               /* Отнять ХП */
                    innerHp.innerHTML = hp;                             /* Вывод ХП */
                }

                if(hp <= 0){
                    alert('Вы проиграли');                              /* Счетчик ХП меньше 0, вы проиграли */
                    buttonEnter.removeEventListener('click', listener);
                    startGame();                                        /* Запуск функции сначала */
                }
            }
        };
        buttonEnter.addEventListener('click', listener);
    }
}
```

```css
body,
html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #7e57c2;
}

.header-button-hide{

}

.header-button{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
}

.header-button:active{
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}

.header-page{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.header-wrap{
    text-align: center;
}

.game-form{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.header-button-hide{
    display: none;
}

.game-form-hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Угадай слово</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header-page">
            <form class="header-wrap" method="GET" action="/start.php">
                <button id="start" class="header-button">Начать</button>
                <button id="stop" class="header-button header-button-hide">Остановить</button>
            </form>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="game">
                <form method="GET" action="/check.php" class="game-form game-form-hide">
                    <h2 class="message"></h2>
                    <p><span>Жизни:</span> <span id="hp"></span></p>
                    <p><span>Подсказка:</span> <span id="hint"></span></p>
                    <p><span>Ваши буквы:</span> <span id="letter"></span></p>
                    <label>Введите букву: <input type="text" name="letter" id="input-letter"></label>
                    <input type="submit" name="enter-letter" id="enter-letter">
                </form>
            </section>
        </main>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```